# Laravel FFMPEG video conversion without waiting for queue

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, laravel-queue, ffmpeg-php

I'm building an application in **Laravel (v9)** where users upload videos, and these get converted to **MP4** (showing progress percentage), thumbnail gets created… etc

Once the video is uploaded, I dispatch a new job in the background that runs all my **FFMPEG** commands, and marks the video as ***ready*** on the database once **FFMPEG** has finished.

However, if there are multiple users uploading multiple videos, this leaves them waiting, as **Laravel’s** queue executes each job one by one.

How can I make it so that videos get converted immediately without waiting for the previous job to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always probably going to want to use a queue, but you could look into increasing the number of queue workers that are running at any given time. Take a look at the [Laravel docs on running your queue via Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) and consider setting the `numprocs` value high enough to support the concurrent load you need to handle.

The caveat is that each queue worker will need CPU/memory, so if you set the number of concurrent workers too high, it may exceed your server's capacity.

You can use [this article on php-fpm tuning](https://cmorrell.com/php-fpm/) to help figure out your server capacity needs. The article is focused on tuning web servers, but you can use the same technique to determine how much memory your queue workers are using, and from there determine how many workers you can reasonably run at once.

One other option would be to look at [Sidecar](https://hammerstone.dev/sidecar/docs/main/overview) to run your ffmpeg processes in AWS Lambdas rather than relying on a queue at all. [This project](https://github.com/binoculars/aws-lambda-ffmpeg) may help you get started…